# Angular Testing - promise not returning data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I can't see why vm.chartData in my HomeCtrl never gets populated with the data i've mocked to it in the beforeEach(). the console.log(scope.vm.chartData) returns undefined even while the other scope vars like graphLoading are defined and changed properly.

```
describe('HomeCtrl', function () {
    var controller, scope, myService, q, $timeout;

    beforeEach(module('dashboardApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $q, _$timeout_) {
        controller = $controller;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $timeout = _$timeout_;
        myService = jasmine.createSpyObj('Chart', ['get']);
        q = $q;
    }));


    describe('when returning promises', function () {

        beforeEach(function () {

            myService.get.and.returnValue(q.when( { result:
                'Stuff'
                }));

            controller('HomeCtrl as vm', { $scope: scope, Chart: myService });
            scope.$apply();

        });

        it('test dirty graph init', function () {
            expect(scope.vm.graphLoading).toBe(true);

            scope.vm.dirtyTestGraph();
            scope.$digest();
            $timeout.flush();

            expect(scope.vm.graphLoading).toBe(false);
            console.log(scope.vm.chartData);
        });
    });
});
```

relevent code from homectrl

```
vm.dirtyTestGraph = function() {
    vm.graphTitle = 'Deposit Amount';
    $timeout(function(){
        Chart.get( { interval:'3h', type:'_type:deposit',
                from:1416960000000, to:Date.now() } )
        .then(function(chart){
            vm.graphLoading = false;
            vm.chartData = chart.data;
        });
    }, 2000);
};
```

and here is the return value of Chart.get in the Chart factory

```
        return $q.all([chartData])
            .then(function(data){
                var graphData = data[0].data.facets[0].entries;
                var newData = [];
                graphData.forEach(function(element){
                    var newElem = {
                        time: element.time,
                        deposits: element.total.toFixed(2)
                    };
                    newData.push(newElem);
                });
                return new Chart(newData);
            });
```

Comment: Have you tried resolving the timeout first and then scope.digest?

Comment: Dont dump all your code and ask people to look into every line of it looking for the actual error. You could do console.log first and detect the possible nested problem where it could be. It save a lot of time for other to solve your issue.

Comment: I have tried swapping the timeout for digest to no effect.

syarul, I'm just showing the one test case and the relevant parts of the controller and factory classes. just so you can see that the Chart.get returns a promise, that vm.chartData is populated after the promise returns, etc. 

I assumed I was missing something obvious having to do with jasmine, sorry for upsetting you.

Comment: Is the actual code have the same problem like the unit test?

Comment: No, the code runs fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller code is looking for a `data` property in the object within the promise returned by `Chart.get`:

```
vm.chartData = chart.data;
```

But your test's stub is returning an object without a `data` property:

```
myService.get.and.returnValue(q.when({
    result: 'Stuff'
}));
```

So `vm.chartData` gets assigned with undefined.